# Make and CMake not detecting file changes on Windows Linux Subsystem when modified from Windows

Tags: windows, makefile, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two different projects, one that uses Make and one that uses CMake. Normally, I expect that when I modify files in these projects Make/Cmake will recompile files that I changed. This is the behavior I observe on Mac and linux systems.

However, I got a new work computer which is a Windows laptop. I am using Make and CMake via the Windows Linux Subsystem, and modifying the code via visual studios code. When I save changes to files and run make, I get

```
make: 'main.exe' is up to date.
```

However, if I modify the same file using vi or vim, make detects the changes and recompiles the relevant source files.

Question: What do I do to get Make to detect changes made via VS code/any text editor when that editor is run in windows?

Comment: When decide whether a file is newer, CMake looks into its **modification time**. Check that modification via VSC actually updates modification file.

Comment: If I use stat to determine the modify time, vi changes this quantity but VS code does not!  Good lead, thanks!